# Solr fetch query use least number?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using one solr query in the code to fetch data collection from solr.
There is a field called 'rank' before I was using in fetch query where condition like "AND (rank:1 OR rank:0)" like this but now I want to change the least number.

For example, my collection doesn't have 0 or 1 but least rank number is 3.
so I want get the list of records having least rank number.

This is my existing query (from logs):

> q=category=nfroots AND (rank=1 OR rank=0)
>
> fq=-isLegacyProduct=true
>
> group=true.

Here is mentioned like category= froots,rank= 0 or 1, isLegacyProduct=true, group=true.

I have to make  rank= instead 0 or 1 it should be least number.

**here is my collection:-**
       {
        "id":"1",
        "rank":"1",
        "name":"A"
        },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "rank":"2",
        "name":"A"
        }
        ,
      {
        "id":"3",
        "rank":"2",
        "name":"B"
        }
        ,
      {
        "id":"4",
        "rank":"3",
        "name":"B"
        }
        ,
      {
        "id":"5",
        "rank":"4",
        "name":"B"
        }

**My Result should be like this :-**
        {
        "id":"1",
        "rank":"1",
        "name":"A"
        },
        {
        "id":"3",
        "rank":"2",
        "name":"B"
        }

Above result, I am trying to get a minimum rank field which is belonged to 'A' and  'B'.

Comment: What about `q=category=nfroots AND rank=3`?

Comment: thanks for your reply :-) but its dynamic population I want to handle from the code.

Comment: You mean you want to show a record with rank=2 only when there is no record with rank=3?

Comment: Two possible solutions - query the index first for the lowest value - using the [stats component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/the-stats-component.html), or sort by rank instead and handle the cutoff point (i.e. when rank changes) in your controller.

Comment: Yes, @UweAllner.